# UIView autoresize problem

Tags: iphone, uiview, resize, autoresize

I have a UIView with several subviews: one UIImageView and a couple of UIViews. When I change the frame property of the view, the imageView's size changes accordingly, but the rest of the subviews remain in their original size!

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Check Autoresizing in IB or code for each of your views.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure **autoresizesSubviews** property of uiview is true.

If that does not work you can resize all subviews by "hand":

```
for (UIView *m_subview in [uiview subviews]) {
        m_subview.frame = newSizeFrame;
        }
```